# Purging without dropping tables - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have for sure a very simple question :

How to purge tables without suppressing them, knowing that they are numbers of key constraints?

Comment: Does a `DELETE FROM <table>` work?

Comment: Use `TRUNCATE TABLE yourTable` in the right order ?

Comment: Delete doesn't work, because of foreign keys, I am going to try truncate

Comment: What's the reason behind this question? What are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code as follows:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
-- your code here
set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

... and Bob's your uncle.